# How to highlight row with maximum cell value in Angular UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an Angular UI Grid, which is defined like

```
 var rowtpl='<div ng-class="{\'extremum\':row.entity.threads==150 }"><div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>';

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableColumnResizing: false,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        multiSelect: false,
        noUnselect: true,
        onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
            gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
                if (row.isSelected) {
                    var importedData = row.entity;
                    DataService.selectedImportedDataId = importedData.id;
                    $scope.selectedData = importedData;
                }
            });
        },
        columnDefs: [
            { name: "Run", field: "run" },
            { name: "Time of Day", field: "tod" },
            { name: "Rate", field: "rate" },
            { name: "MB/sec", field: "mbps" },
            { name: "Response", field: "resp" },
            { name: "xfersize", field: "xfersize" },
            { name: "Threads", field: "threads" },
            { name: "queue_depth", field: "queue_depth" },
            { name: "Read %", field: "read_percentage" },
            { name: "Read response", field: "read_resp" },
            { name: "Write response", field: "write_resp" },
            { name: "lunsize", field: "lunsize" }
        ],
        data: [],
        rowTemplate: rowtpl
    };
```

(Data is loaded outside of this code).
Here is my HTML, Testcontroller is name of my controller.

```
 <div ng-controller="TestController" class="row">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div ui-grid="gridOptions"
                 ui-grid-edit
                 ui-grid-auto-resize
                 ui-grid-selection
                 ui-grid-save-state>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code creates a table with one row highlighted (row is selected with `row.entity.threads==150` in my row template). Can I highlight the row with the  value not selected by myself, but with maximum or minimum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way.

Your Row template:

```
var rowtpl='<div ng-class="{\'extremum\':row.entity.threads==150, \'highlight\':row.entity.isMaximum }"><div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>';
```

You need to add `highlight` class to your css.
When you are getting a data, you can loop through it to check the maximum value and set a flag `entity.isMaximum = true`.

For calculating maximum in your data array, you can use any of the maximum finding function in javascript. One such function is available in `UnderscoreJS`
Sample implementation is as below.

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.max(stooges, function(stooge){ return stooge.age; });
=> {name: 'curly', age: 60};
```

If you are still getting any issues with this solution, please post your data object.

Comment: Not needed. You can add your own property. Its not mandatory to have it mapped to your column